# Convergence of $\sum\limits _{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^n (2 i)^{-n-1} \binom{-1/2}{n/2}}{2^n}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am interested in the series
$$
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty }{\left(-1\right)^{n}\,\left(\,2i\,\right)^{-n - 1} \over 2^{n}}\,
{-1/2 \choose n/2}
$$
I have read in a forum that it converges. Can anyone explain why?

Comment: Why not simplify the summands? Those constants can be tossed together...

Comment: How do you define $-1/2\choose{n/2}$ when $n$ is odd?

Comment: Is $\large i = \sqrt{\,-1\,}\ $ ?.

Comment: @SteveKass $\displaystyle{{-1/2 \choose n/2} = {\Gamma\left(1/2\right) \over \Gamma\left(n/2 + 1\right)\Gamma\left(1/2 - n/2\right)}}$.

Comment: @Marin: Or more concisely (when n is odd), zero. 

Since ${-1/2\choose{n/2}}=0$ when $n$ is odd, the sum be rewritten a little less obscurely, no?

For what it's worth, Mathematica evaluates the sum as $-\frac{i}{\sqrt{15}}$.

Comment: @SteveKass  Yes. The coefficient can be written as
$\displaystyle{\large{-1/2 \choose n/2} = {1 \over \sqrt{\pi}}\,{\Gamma\left(1/2 + n/2\right) \over \Gamma\left(1 + n/2\right)}\,\cos\left(n\pi \over 2\right)}$.

Comment: @SteveKass I did a long calculation of it. I deleted it since the OP never answer whether $\large i = \sqrt{-1}$ or it's a constant. At the end of the calculation, I need to know that. I'll undelete it whenever the OP answer this question.

Comment: @SteveKass Moreover, $\displaystyle{{-1/2 \choose n} = {1 \over 4}\,\left(-4\right)^{n}{2n \choose n}}$. You are left with a sum which looks like $\displaystyle{\large \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}z^{n}{2n \choose n}}$. In performing this sum I need to know what is $\large i$.

Comment: i is the i complex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is nothing else than **Newton's** famous [binomial theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series), extended to non-natural powers :

$$S=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{2^n\cdot(2i)^{n+1}}\cdot C_{-\frac12}^{\frac n2}\ =\ \frac1{2i}\cdot\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{-1}{2\cdot2i}\right)^n\cdot C_{-\frac12}^{\frac n2}\ =-\frac i2\cdot\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac i4\right)^n\cdot C_{-\frac12}^{\frac n2}\ =\ ...$$

But since for $n=2k+1$ the odd terms vanish because $C_{-\frac12}^{\frac n2}=0$, we are only left with :

$$=-\frac i2\cdot\sum_{k=0}^\infty\left(\frac i4\right)^{2k}\cdot C_{-\frac12}^k=-\frac i2\cdot\sum_{k=0}^\infty\left(-\frac1{16}\right)^k\cdot C_{-\frac12}^k=-\frac i2\cdot\left(1-\frac1{16}\right)^{-\frac12}=$$

$$=-\frac i2\cdot\frac1{\sqrt\frac{15}{16}}=-\frac i2\cdot\frac4{\sqrt{15}}=-\frac{2i}{\sqrt{15}}\qquad\mathcal{Q.E.D.}$$

Comment: well done Lucian

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Prove the series converges absolutely.